# css overflow hidden override with selector

Tags: html, css

I made a complex page and I allways had this annoying scroll, so my solution was to do

```
html{
overflow-y:hidden;
overflow-x:hidden:
}
```

which works great, but then i decided to make another page which I want the overflow to show, how do I override this? I tried to make a container and put `overflow-y:visible and overflow-x:visible` but that simply won't work, changing  the html selector only breaks the previous page, is there something to do?

Comment: why don't you add overflow property to the page specific? rather than applying it to the complete html?

Comment: Don't target `html` element for this, in your first complex page have a container of its own and in there hide the overflow

Comment: I would try adding a class to the new page so you can override the original `html` css with that: `html.new-page { override css here }`

Comment: you may also set the overflow on body instead. no need to re-reset html then

Comment: @G-Cyr on body it doesn't work the way I want it...

Comment: @hussain.codes I tried wrapping it with a container and setting the overflow:hidden, but that simply didnt work, I don't know why

Comment: @Teknotica I'm sorry i don't understand how to implement your suggestion

Comment: @AlexK try setting `max-width:100%` to the container and then set `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @hussain.codes doesn't work =\

Comment: In which way it doesn't work ? `body/*.thatpage */{margin:0; height:100vh; width:100vw; overflow:auto; }` should lay itself where html does and do the overflow you want. , you can also set your own size and margins ...

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the body tag like this `<body class="overflow-true">` in page you want scroll and in **css file** add a property to the **.overflow-true** like

`html .overflow-true { overflow: scroll }`

and this should work.

Comment: this works only if you give a size to body to trigger scroll possibilities when needed

Comment: You can give width and height as 100%

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code {overflow-y:hidden;} {overflow-x:hidden:}

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  overflow: scroll;
}

ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* decorations. */

ul {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

li:before,
li:after {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: larger;
  content: "::";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: no size, no scrol , you forgot `html{
overflow-y:hidden;
overflow-x:hidden:
}`